# PHP and HTML Logging in

Tags: php, html, logging

I'm trying to make log in and register script with php and html. It doesn't work and i ant press a button. What am i doing wrong? I'm new to programming sites.This is HTML :

Register:

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
<input  type=text name="uid" /><br/></form>
<form action="register.php" method="post">
<input type="password" name="pass" /><br/>
</form>

<input type="submit" action="register.php" name="R" value="Sign Up" />
```

PHP:

```
require "sqlconnect.php"


$pass=$_POST("pass")
$uid=$_POST("uid")
$clicked=$_POST("R")


if($uid and $pass) { 

 connection()

 $ins = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO Users SET id='$uid', pass='$pass'"); 

 if($ins) 
 echo "Registered!You can log in now :)";
 header("Location: index2.php"); 

 else echo "Error!"; 

mysql_close($connection);
```

Log in:

```
<center><cc><b>Please login to proceed:</b></cc></center>
<center><form action="login.php" method="post" style="border-color:#0068AD" >
<input  type=text name="uid" /><br/></form>
<form action="login.php" method="post" style="border-color:#0068AD" >
<input type="password" name="pass" /><br/>
</form>
<input type="submit" action="login.php" name="L" value="Log in"/><br/>
<center><cc><a href="register.html"> Register </a></cc></center>
```

PHP:

```
 require "sqlconnect.php"

connection()


$pass=$_POST("pass")
$uid=$_POST"uid")
$clicked=$_POST("L")

$pass = "SELECT `pass` FROM `Users` WHERE `id`='$uid'";
$passcheck = mysql_query($pass);

    if($clicked>1||$passcheck=true)
        header=index3.html
        elseif(clicked>1||passcheck=false)
            echo ("Wrong username or password")


 mysql_close($connection)
```

Comment: `What am i doing wrong?` Nearly everything

Comment: Maybe you should look it up on google; so many good tutorials on this subject out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `submit` button needs to be inside your `form` element, and you should have all inputs inside the same (single form)

HTML should be something like:

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
  <b>Username:</b> <input type="text" name="uid" /><br/>
  <b>Password:</b> <input type="password" name="pass" /><br/>
  <input type="submit" name="R" value="Sign Up" />
</form>
```

While your PHP for retrieving data from the $_POST array should be:

```
$pass=$_POST["pass"];
$uid=$_POST["uid"];
```

And you should be escaping both those values before you include them in a SQL statement (to prevent SQL injection).

So your `$pass` line should be something like:

```
$pass = "SELECT `pass` FROM `Users` WHERE `id`='"+
   mysql_real_escape_string($uid)+"'";
```

And your `$ins` line should be something like:

```
$ins = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO Users SET id='".mysql_real_escape_string($uid)+
   "', pass='"+mysql_real_escape_string($pass)+"'");
```

And you should be either hashing or encrypting people's passwords before storing.

Answer (score 3):

wow. there are a lot of mistakes

```
$pass=$_POST("pass")
$uid=$_POST("uid")
$clicked=$_POST("R")
```

should be

```
$pass=$_POST["pass"];
$uid=$_POST["uid"];
$clicked=$_POST["R"];
```

you forgot a lot of semicolons

form should look like

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" style="border-color:#0068AD" >
    <input type="password" name="pass" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" action="login.php" name="L" value="Log in"/>
</form>
<br/>
```

(submit must be in form)

Comment: Good catch, I didn't even notice that.  The OP should definitely look at his PHP error logs.

Answer (score 1):

Your `form`s are broken.  All of your inputs need to be inside one `form` in order to all be submitted in the same POST:

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
  <input type=text name="uid" /><br/>
  <input type="password" name="pass" /><br/>
  <input type="submit" action="register.php" name="R" value="Sign Up" />
</form>
```

And:

```
<center><cc><b>Please login to proceed:</b></cc></center>
<center>
  <form action="login.php" method="post" style="border-color:#0068AD" >
    <input type=text name="uid" /><br/>
    <input type="password" name="pass" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" action="login.php" name="L" value="Log in"/><br/>
  </form>
</center>
<center><cc><a href="register.html"> Register </a></cc></center>
```

(Also, it's best not to use the `center` tag anymore.  I understand that you're just getting started, but you'll want look into using [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) for your styling sooner rather than later.  It will lead to much cleaner and easier to manage HTML markup.)

Comment: @genesis φ: Indeed, there is much to be improved here.

Answer (score 1):

This is my best guess at what you were trying to do based on the original code. I would like to see inside `sqlconnect.php` to see what's going on in there...

Corrections are FAR too numerous to mention, ask specific questions about anything you don't understand...

---

**Register**

HTML:

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
    <!-- forms should contain ONLY block level elements as direct children! -->
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="uid" /><br/>
        <input type="password" name="pass" /><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$pass = $_POST["pass"];
$uid = $_POST["uid"];

if ($uid and $pass) { 
    require "sqlconnect.php";
    connection();
    $ins = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Users` (`id`,`pass`) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($uid)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($pass)."')"); 
    if ($ins) {
        echo "Registered! You can log in now :)";
        header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found');
        header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/index2.php");
    } else echo "Error!";
    mysql_close($connection);
}
```

---

**Log In**

HTML:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" style="border-color:#0068AD;">
    <div>
        <center><b>Please login to proceed:</b></center><br/>
        <center><input type="text" name="uid" /><br/>
        <center><input type="password" name="pass" /></center><br/>
        <center><input type="submit" value="Log in"/></center>
    </div>
</form>
<center><a href="register.html">Register</a></center>
```

PHP:

```
require "sqlconnect.php";
connection();


$pass = $_POST["pass"];
$uid = $_POST["uid"];

if (!$passcheck = mysql_query("SELECT `pass` FROM `Users` WHERE `id`='".mysql_real_escape_string($uid)."'")) die('MySQL Error');
$passcheck = mysql_fetch_assoc($passcheck);
mysql_close($connection);

if ($passcheck['pass'] == $pass) {
  header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found');
  header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/index3.html");
} else echo ("Wrong username or password");
```

Answer (score 0):

All fields and the button should be inside the same form. Don't use a different form for each one. I'm on mobile, so I can't post code. Left as community wiki so people will add it.

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button should be inside your form, otherwise it won't know what to submit. You should also review the security of your form, when interacting with the database you should always sanitise data with [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

So it should read:

```
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["pass"]);
$uid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["uid"]);
$clicked = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["L"]);
```

You're also missing a lot of semi-colons which should go at the end of every single line as shown above.

You should also use double equal signs (==) or triple equals sign (===) when comparing statements in an if statement, so yours should read:

```
if($clicked> 1 || $passcheck == true)
```

You should also include curly braces, so the full if should look like:

```
if($clicked>1||$passcheck=true) {
    header = index3.html; //This should probably be header = 'index3.html'
} elseif(clicked> 1 || passcheck == false) {
    echo ("Wrong username or password");
}
```

I've probably missed some, but there are lots of errors.

Comment: How should i put them in the same form?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance your SQL INSERT statement is incorrect. It should be `INSERT INTO users (id,pass) VALUES ('$id','$pass')`. There are also a lot of syntax errors that you'll need to look into.